Error "OpenCV not found" when building AAR for Android library using OpenCV
I'm developing an Android library that includes OpenCV as a dependency. I'm encountering an issue where, after building the AAR file and trying to use it in another project, I get an error stating that "OpenCVLoader class not found."Error Log
Things I've tried -

Adding openCV as Module and building the AAR
Adding openCV as dependency - "implementation ('org.opencv:opencv:4.10.0')" then building both the cases gives me the same error.

My build.gradle file for the library is -
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.android.library)
    alias(libs.plugins.jetbrains.kotlin.android)
    id 'maven-publish'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.msn.nqrscannerlib'
    compileSdk 34

    defaultConfig {
        minSdk 24

        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        consumerProguardFiles "consumer-rules.pro"
        ndk {
            abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a', 'x86', 'x86_64'
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "17"
    }
    viewBinding {
        enabled = true
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['src/main/jniLibs']
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        pickFirst("lib/arm64-v8a/libopencv_java4.so")
        pickFirst("lib/x86_64/libopencv_java4.so")
        pickFirst("lib/x86/libopencv_java4.so")
        pickFirst("lib/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_java4.so")
    }
}

publishing {
    publications {
        bar(MavenPublication) {
            groupId = 'com.msn'
            artifactId = 'nqrscannerlib'
            version = '1.0.10-alpha'
            artifact("$buildDir/outputs/aar/nqrScannerLib-release.aar")
        }
    }
    repositories {
        maven {
            name "GithubPackages"
            url uri("https://maven.pkg.github.com/xxx/xxx")
            credentials {
                username = "xxxxx"
                password = "xxxxxx"
            }
        }
    }
}


dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation libs.androidx.core.ktx
    implementation libs.androidx.appcompat
    implementation libs.material
    implementation libs.androidx.activity
    implementation libs.androidx.constraintlayout
    testImplementation libs.junit
    androidTestImplementation libs.androidx.junit
    androidTestImplementation libs.androidx.espresso.core
    var camerax_version = "1.3.4"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-core:$camerax_version"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-camera2:$camerax_version"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-lifecycle:$camerax_version"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-view:$camerax_version"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-video:$camerax_version"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.3.1"
    implementation ('org.opencv:opencv:4.10.0')
    implementation(libs.okhttp)
    implementation(libs.kotlinx.coroutines.core)
    implementation(libs.kotlinx.coroutines.android)
    implementation libs.barcode.scanning
    implementation libs.play.services.mlkit.barcode.scanning
}


Welcome to Stackoverflow! Images are useful in a post, but make sure the post is still clear without them. If you post images of code or - in your case - error messages, copy and paste or type the actual code or message into the post directly. See Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.
